# Multiple compile-time checks with the same bool value. How to check just once?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Consider this code:

```
template <int A, int B, typename T>
struct Object {
    static constexpr bool check = A < B;
    static constexpr int value = check ? A : A+1;
    static constexpr char c = check ? 'a' : 'b';
    static constexpr double d = check ? 1.5 : 3.14;
    using type = typename std::conditional<check, T, int>::type;
    // etc...
};
```

How to rewrite the above so that `check` needs only be checked once?  After all, it is the same value throughout.  Everything must be constexpr.

Comment: Since they're already all `constexpr`, does it matter?

Comment: That is a pointless (compile-time) optimization. I'm sure the compiler can do it itself... and you dont have to worry about it. Even if it cannot, it isn't worth spending your time on such thing, as it is negligible.

Comment: Are you trying to speed up compilation time?  There is no run time overhead for this.

Comment: All the LHS constexpr's 'value', 'c' and 'd' are distinctly named ones. If one were to combine them, by reusing the 'check ?' expression, you would need a statement. It no longer is a constexpr. You don't want that right. In any case, you don't pay any run-time for doing multiple 'check ? _ : _'. I don't see any need to think about this.

Comment: @Nawaz: Presumably the goal is to improve readibility (replacing the squiggly conditional expressions with two sets of simpler unconditional expressions), not compilation speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by @Nawaz, the optimization is pointless. There will not be any runtime benefit and compiler is smart enough to optimize the conditions during compile time so there should not be much overhead during compile time.

In any case, what you are envisaging is possible, provided you agree to take the template specialization route. You can split the condition into two separate specialization and utilize them to determine the appropriate `constexpr` applicable for your problem.

```
template <int A, int B, typename T, bool check = A / B >
    struct Object {
        static constexpr  int value = A;
        static constexpr  char c = 'a';
        static constexpr  double d = 1.5;
        using type = T;
        // etc...
    };
    template <int A, int B, typename T>
    struct Object<A,B,T,false> {
        static constexpr  int value =  A + 1;
        static constexpr  char c = 'b';
        static constexpr  double d =  3.14;
        using type = int;
        // etc...
    };
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Not actually, this happens when you don;t pay attention while copy pasting the code.

Comment: I think you mean `bool check = A < B`.

Comment: What about constexpr values that are the same in both specializations?   Say `static constexpr bool b = A+B > 10;`, which is the case regardless of what `check` is?  Do we just repeat them?  Or have both specializations inherit from `template <int A, int B> struct ObjectCommon { static constexpr bool b = A+B > 10; };`

Comment: @prestokeys: I would suggest you to group the common values and inherit them.

Answer (score 1):

You may pack all constant into `tuple`

```
template <int A, int B, typename T>
struct Object {
private:
    static constexpr std::tuple<bool, int, char, double> t = (A < B) ?
        { true, A, 'a', 1.5 } :
        { false, B, 'b', 3.14};
public:
    static constexpr bool check = std::get<0>(t);
    static constexpr int value = std::get<1>(t);
    static constexpr char c = std::get<2>(t);
    static constexpr double d = std::get<3>(t);;
    using type = typename std::conditional<check, T, int>::type;
    // etc...
};
```

but not sure it was better.